# Why function exp() first run so slow when it is called in a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, exp

I want to calculate some data in a for-loop.when I use exp(),I found it run so slow when it is first called.I use clock gettime to time it.when it is called firstly,it took about 6000ns,while subsequent calls took only about 200ns.My gcc version is "gcc 版本 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) (GCC) ".I have tried to look over its assembler code,there is no  special treatment. I wonder why this happened?

my test code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
double getCurrentTimestamp() {
        timespec a;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &a);
        return ((double(a.tv_nsec) * 1.0e-9) + double(a.tv_sec));
}
int main(){
    double a[]={0.12345,0.23456,0.22123};
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        double start_time1 = getCurrentTimestamp();
        double c = exp(a[i]);
        double end_time1 = getCurrentTimestamp();
        double total_time1 = (end_time1 - start_time1);
        printf("total_time1 is %0.6fms\n", total_time1 * 1e3);
        printf("c:%0.15f\n",c);

    }
}
```

the test result is

```
total_time1 is 0.005283ms
c:1.131393433456141
total_time1 is 0.000192ms
c:1.264352331299862
total_time1 is 0.000143ms
c:1.247610347947329
```

Comment: It's hard to know, from the information you have given.  One possibility is that the first call of `exp()` initialises some table that is used to speed things up in later calls.  Another possibility is that the math library is dynamically linked, and the library must be loaded during the first call of a function in the math library.   A third possible reason is jitter in the `clock_gettime()` function - which is why most performance measurements are based on a LARGE number of calculations (to get a statistical average) rather than trying to time the calls of individual library functions.

Comment: I was actually thinking of spatial locality. Wouldn't it apply in this case?

Comment: Possibly.  But it's one possible factor of several.   Without knowing how your compiler emits instructions, how memory is organised at program startup, what caching your processor does, etc, it's impossible to say.

Comment: To add to @Peter: For benchmarking, I often saw that they are started with some unmeasured iterations first. That's intended to "heat up" the CPU because modern computers/systems may lower the speed of CPUs when a certain amount of idle time is recognized. E.g. my laptop with 8 cores is idling most the time except I start a compiler for a big project or run one of our expensive simulations...

Comment: @Peter,Thank you very much for your advice. I tried a new test. I call the exp() before the for-loop.when I call like these "double d = exp(a[0]);" the calls in for-loop all take only about 200ns while when I call like these "double d = exp(0.111);" ,the phenomenon is the same as before. So time should have been spent on the array initialization-related operations.Because I'm working on a project that requires a lot of time accuracy,So is there any good advice to get these done ahead of time?

Comment: If calling exp() with a[0] first accelerates subsequent calls to exp() while calling exp() with a random value doesn't, I would look at memory access issues. Depending on optimizations, a[] might not be initialized before it is actually used inside the loop. Also, it might be initialized from constants stored at a distant address in your binary. It might then incur a page fault which takes time to handle. This is highly hypothetical, however. Try to simply read a[0] before entering the loop (by copying it to a volatile double for instance) to see if it helps.

Comment: @Meatboy 106 ,it doesn't work.only call exp(a[i]) can accelerates subsequent calls.other method likes pow(),log() don't work . I guess what special optimization happens when exp calls array elements,but I don't have a way to verify it.